piece-id, part-id, piece-name? No one's going to tag things right
Right now we have piece-id, part-id, and piece-name tags.
I don't think this is a good approach. No new user is ever going to tag these right, and it's not like a question for a piece name is practically different than a question asking for a piece's element ID. And beyond that, identifications of non-pieces like stickers or entire sets should really be sharing a tag - we use the same resources to answer the question.
If no one objects, I'd like to merge all three of those into the single identification tag.

I think @Dori asked a question along the same lines on the chat, but didn't get much answers. I agree on [tag:identification], whether people are after the name, element id or design id is basically irrelevant. The only issue I can see is if we also get a lot of set identification requests also, but I doun't we'll get much, and surely not enough to justify creating two tags.

I think merging set identification and part identification requests is a plus. Set identification always starts with part identification so they'll use the same resources and knowledge.

Agreed, not only is there probably no need to separate both, but there are indeed good reasons to keep them together.

Whatever the choice may be, some tag wikis would help.

@Dori's chat post was: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2261055#2261055 I also agree we should merge those. Leave [tag:piece-information] separate as that's more about the history/context of pieces than knowing what they are called/referred to.

Need to get @oezi in here as a user with rights to do this ;)

I recall some complaints from another SE about lack of tag merging/renaming - you can set up pre-hoc synonyms, but the only way to really merge is to retag questions by hand. So, I just did that.

As you say, we still need to get the synonyms in place so that they don't creep back.

We now have two separate tags for piece-information and indetification.
Piece Information

Questions asking for information about a known LEGO element/brick. Use
  identification for questions about unknown pieces or sets.

Synonym: parts
Indentification

Use this tag if you are trying to identify a LEGO element or set that
  you possess or have seen somewhere.

Synonym: piece-id

Users are encouraged to add an improve to existing tags, as they would with questions and answers. 
